# Flex: How to position a popup inside a scrollable container?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex4.5

I have created a component called Notification Bubble which is a skinnablePopUpContainer that should be placed on top of other component on top-right edge as popup. I have problem when my owner component is in scrollable area. If user scroll the container then the owner is moving inside the viewport but my poup resides on the same place. I have added the UPDATE_COMPLETE listener to the owner but it re-position the bubble only when user mouse over or any update happens.

[Git Link for NotificationBubble.as](https://github.com/flexdevguy/NotificationBubble/blob/master/src/bubble/NotificationBubble.as)

[image]

Comment: You might not be able to do this directly, as the PopUp is always on top of the display list. You could, however use a [PopUpAnchor](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/PopUpAnchor.html) to position the PopUp. Don't know, if this works in a scrollable container, though.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should using

```
localToGlobal
```

function